# R Server HD Insight Cluster Host key verification failed

Tags: r, azure, ssh, azure-hdinsight

I set up an HD Insight Cluster running R Server using a Putty instigated SSH tunnel.  When I go to use the `RxSpark()` function and specify my username, hostname, etc. I get a returned error message that states:

> Host key verification failed. Please validate host connection using
>   the specified ssh tool directly and try again.

How am I supposed to validate the host connection?

Comment: Try to putty back in and see if you are using the right password. Something may not be set up as you thought, or you may not have given yourself appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you run your script there are two possibilities:
1. If you run it on the edge node of HDInsight cluster - you don't need to specify ssh credentials and RxSpark should just work as it's in the cluster already.
2. If you run your script on the local machine outside of the cluster - then you need to use ssh session auth with key - password won't work.

Let me know what specific configuration you have.

Maxim